# Swapping to new grub after clean installation on a new drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I used to run Ubuntu off my old ssd on /dev/sda which has partitions :

- sda1 - EFI partition (500 mb fat)
- sda2 - Linux filesystem (258 mb ext2)
- sda3 - Linux LVM. (119 gb lvm2 pv)

I recently bought a new ssd which I hooked into /dev/sdd, with the intent of moving all of my data and boot processes to this new disk, and eventually wiping the old one and using it as storage.

Thus I got a new linux image, threw it on an flash, booted from it, and installed linux on this new sdd drive. I ended up creating partitions:

- sdd1 -  a main bootable ext4 partition (983 gb)
- sdd2 - extended partition (17 gb)
- sdd5 - linux swap (17 gb)

When I currently boot, grub comes up on launch and asks where to boot from. I can boot from both my old sda and my new sdd just fine manually selecting from the grub menu. I *think* im ready to wipe out the old sda drive, but I want to ensure I have a grub install on the new one that will replace the old one.
Though I do have a bootable install on the new sdd, I worry that maybe grub only exists on sda and I will destroy my boot.

I am a bit uncomfortable with the types of partitions I created and have on the new sdd, and really all I want is a partition for everything ( or maybe one for boot  & one for data depending on best practices), and one for swap. I have no clue if this extended partition I already have is holding the already existing new grub, is doing anything at all, or maybe it can be used to install the new grub. Clearly sdd1 is being used to boot off and contains all of the data right now when I use boot through sdd.... just is it ready to hold its own weight after I shut off the old drive?

Really any tips, advice or links on how to make this process easier would be appreciated. Thanks!

PS. Where did my sdd3/4 go??? Its not like I need them, but did I do something funky while partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your new (`/dev/sdd`) disk uses the old [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system, which *probably* means Ubuntu is installed to it in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Your original (`/dev/sda`) disk, OTOH, seems to use the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) system, and it probably booted in EFI/UEFI mode. I can't be positive of that from the information you presented, though. (As a general tip, *do not summarized program output;* instead, cut-and-paste such output or provide screen shots. The output of `sudo parted -l` would remove all doubt about your partition layout.)

If I'm right about your partitions and boot modes, then the presence or absence of a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi` will tell from which installation's GRUB you're booting. If that directory is present, you've booted in EFI mode (and hence from the original installation); and if it's absent, you're in BIOS mode (and hence booted from the new installation). Given the slightly lower than 100% certainty about your partitions and boot modes, though, there will be some uncertainty about that -- maybe a 2% chance of being wrong.

You could also learn something by examining the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` files on both your installations and comparing them to what you see when you boot the computer. That file's format is very complex, though.

You can get some insurance by downloading the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) It should enable you to boot either installation in EFI mode. (To boot the old installation directly from its kernel, though, you'll need to hit F2 or Insert and add a `root=` parameter to identify the root (`/`) filesystem.) If you obtain and test rEFInd on a CD-R or USB flash drive, you'll be prepared in case wiping your old disk renders the system unbootable; you should then still be able to boot the new system and make repairs.